# Word or idiom for something that can either be helpful or harmful, depending on how it's used

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

For example, consider the following:

> Knives are a [*blank*], because they can either be used as a tool or a weapon.

I don't think "double-edged sword" is appropriate in this context because that idiom implies the object is simultaneously helpful and harmful. I'm instead, searching for a word or phrase to describe something that is either helpful or harmful depending on how it is used.

Comment: Double-edged sword is what you want. It means [*something that has or can have both favorable and unfavorable consequences*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-edged%20sword). Note the "can have" meaning, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A single word or phrase for something that necessarily causes both harm and benefit?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347061/a-single-word-or-phrase-for-something-that-necessarily-causes-both-harm-and-bene)

Comment: 'double-edged sword' / 'mixed blessing' / 'cuts both ways' /  given in previous threads.

Comment: How about "One man's meat is another man's poison". https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+man%27s+meat+is+another+man%27s+poison

Answer (score 2):

***work both ways***

> If something such as a particular situation or type of behaviour works both ways, it has equal advantages and disadvantages for everyone it involves

> - We are expected to be very flexible, but that should work both ways. ([macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work-both-ways#work-both-ways__1))

Comment: Worth noting that *cuts both ways* could be more apt here, since it's a knife.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin *Cuts both ways* is from the same origin as [*double-edged sword" in fact](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double-edged_sword).

Comment: *Work both ways* differs in that it is expressing a reciprocal relationship. And in fact in Macmillan's own example, that's more like the more common usage: [1. To have comparable effects for both parties involved in something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/works+both+ways)

Answer (score 2):

> Knives are **a blessing and a curse**, because they can either be used as a tool or a weapon.

The expression comes from the [Geneva translation of the Bible (1561), Deuteronomy 11:26-28](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A10675.0001.001/1:5.5.11?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div3;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a%20blessing%20and%20a%20curse):

> 26 ¶ Beholde, I set before you this day **a bles∣sing and a curse**:
>
> 27 * The blessing, if ye obey the commande∣ments* of the Lord your God which I com¦mande you this day:
>
> 28 And the curse, if ye wil not obey the com¦mandements of the Lord your God, but turne out of the way, which I cōmande you this day, to go after other gods, which ye haue not knowen.

The phrasing made it into the [King James Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2011%3A26-28&version=KJV) virtually unchanged, and the expression then took on a life of it own (see the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_blessing_and_a_curse) entry). While its uses are sometimes religious, it's not hard to find secular uses that have the gist you mean, namely that the knife could be helpful or harmful:

- "Russian Energy: A Blessing and a Curse" ([title of academic article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24357785))
- "No One's Like Giannis, But That's A Blessing and A Curse" ([title of sports article](https://www.si.com/nba/2021/06/17/giannis-antetokounmpo-bucks-nets-nba-playoffs))
- "ADHD can be a blessing and a curse" ([title of article on school website](https://centeracademy.com/adhd-can-be-a-blessing-and-a-curse/))

Answer (score 1):

**Mixed Blessing**

> something that has advantages and disadvantages

*Getting into the team is a mixed blessing - I'll have to spend a lot of time training.*

[Cambridge Dictionary]

You could therefore say *Knives are a **mixed blessing**, because they can either be used as a tool or a weapon.*

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best option is ["can cut both ways"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+cut+both+ways%2C+may+cut+both+ways%2C+might+cut+both+ways&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20cut%20both%20ways%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmay%20cut%20both%20ways%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmight%20cut%20both%20ways%3B%2Cc0t1) implying that the negative or positive effects are not guaranteed. Unlike the simple ["cuts both ways"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cut-both-ways) which means that the effects are both assumed.

E.g.
[Empathy Can Cut Both Ways](https://washingtonmonthly.com/2009/05/27/empathy-can-cut-both-ways/)

[A Ritual That Can Cut Both Ways](https://www.ritualwell.org/blog/ritual-can-cut-both-ways)

[Feeling emotionally connected to your client can cut both ways](https://www.investmentwriting.com/feeling-emotionally-connected-to-your-client-can-cut-both-ways/)

Answer (score 0):

> “A good servant, but a bad master”

[This proverb originally (1615) was used in a comparison with **fire**](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199539536.001.0001/acref-9780199539536-e-789), and I learned it in this respect as a schoolboy (many, many years ago). It can apply equally — and, in my opinion, quite elegantly — in this case.